# In Centos 6 / Windows 10 dual boot, overwritten partition by Windows bootloader

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, data-recovery, boot-loader

In a previous Centos 6 install, Windows 10 was installed months ago and the Centos 6 GRUB file was updated to select dual boot by disk name.

Recently, due to some kind of error in a reboot, the disk order was changed and Windows tried to boot from an array partition (which contained no OS, only data), destroying it and just leaving a 150 something Mb boot partition where there was a full disk XFS partition.

Now I have that array in this state:

GUID partition table

+150 something Mb NTFS file system (presumably the Windows boot partition that destroyed the previous partition)
+10 Tb empty space

I am sure the disk was overwritten by Windows boot and I need to restore the previous partition and access the previous data, but I'm doubting which is the best procedure in this case:

a) Should I delete the NTFS boot partition and try a full testdisk disk recovery?
b) Should I delete the NTFS boot partition and use fdisk or similar to automagically restore the previous partition?
c) Should I use low-level recovery software to try to recover as much raw data as possible since all hope of a clean restore is gone?

Comment: The best approach would be simply to restore from backups.

Comment: But recovery wise, in case you don't have a backup, how would you do it?

Comment: A full clone of the entire drive and then you can try Testdisk and other stuff on the clone. If you screw up badly, repeat the cloning and try again. Unfortunately I have not much knowledge about XFS, but it's safe to assume that at least important data was backed up.

Comment: Thank you, I tried Testdisk but sadly no major partition was found, only small fragments that weren't recoverable.

Then I tried xfs_repair first:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/xfsrepair

And I could recover around 200 Mb files.

Answer (score 0):

The best procedures to recover files in xfs appear to be:

1. **xfs_repair** - [Link to documentation](http://docs.cray.com/books/S-2377-22/html-S-2377-22/z1029470303.html)
   Included or downloadable in several GNU/Linux distributions.

   *xfs_check /dev/device* --> Analyze the disk (no writing)
   *xfs_repair -n* --> A more in-depth analysis (no writing)

   *xfs_repair* --> Actual recovery (writing)
2. **testdisk** - [Link to documentation](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)
   Free software included in Gparted.

   Follow the steps in the documentation link.
3. **UFS Explorer** - [Link to product](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/download_pro.php)
   Commercial proprietary software.

   Recovery with user friendly GUI, could work if 1. and 2. fail.